# Mysql array in shell script (Linux)

Tags: mysql, arrays, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to read out ids from mysql and then delete the entry with id-1.

```
today_time=$(date -d "now" '+%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')  
query_find_id="SELECT id FROM guestlist WHERE value <= '$today_time'"

array_query=$(mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWORD $TABLE_NAME -e "$query_find_id")

array_id=($(for i in $array_query; do echo $i; done))

for j in "${array_id[@]}"; k=$j-1; mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWORD $TABLE_NAME -e "DELETE FROM guestlist WHERE id = '$k'"; done
```

The array is empty every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: learn to use `set -vx` and examine the output from each line. You would probably see that `query_find_id` is empty when you get to the 3rd line. (Agreeing about answer from @tgx.) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

If your `value` column is a DATETIME, your date format in `today_time` should be **`%Y-%m-%d`**`%H:%M:%S`.

Comment: Actually my value in the list is something like '12 Sep 2014 15:00:00'

Comment: You're using `WHERE value <= '$today_time'` in your query. What column type is `value`?